# How do I make line 25 execute?

Tags: reactjs

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

function App() {
 
  function test(){
    /* eslint-disable no-undef */
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow:true}, tabs=>{
      const activeTabId = tabs[0].id;
      
      chrome.scripting.executeScript(
        {
          target: {tabId: activeTabId},
          function: ()=>{
           
            var tab= document.getElementsByClassName("styles__BodyRow-sc-4myuz0-3 cnRgPY");
            var list=[];
           
            for(var i=0;i<tab.length;i++){
              if(tab[i].children[7].innerText!="$0.00"){
                tab[i].style['background-color']="red";

               

                  id = "success";


                
              }
            }
            
           
          }
          
        }
      )
    })
  }


      var id = "try again";

    const [OrderID, setOrderNumber] = useState(id);
    const [Date, setDate] = useState("");
    const [DasherName, setDasher] = useState("");
    const [Cost, setCost] = useState("");
  
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
  
      const object = { OrderID, Date, DasherName, Cost };
  
      axios
        .post(
          "https://sheet.best/api/sheets/****************************",
          object
        )
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        });
    };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={test}>Search</button>
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Paste</button>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Whenever I run the program, I get "try again" instead of "sucess". I think I should make the variable id global but idk how to. I been trying for so long, but I can't seem to make the variable id global so that when I run handleSubmit, it outputs success. Everything else works (this is a web scrapper for my computer science project). I am wondering if I can do something so that the handleSubmit button can reach the id within the test function. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you used your step-through debugger? If not, why not?

Comment: I have used it, but I can't seem to get it to work. I have tried everything

Comment: I don't know where I am going wrong

Comment: You can't get your debugger to work?  What IDE are you using?  Chrome/Developer Tools?  MS Visual Studio Code?  Other? Being able to compile and run your React app is the 1st priority; being able to use the debugger is a close 2nd.

Comment: I am using VSC.

Comment: My code works, but it doesn't print out "success" instead it prints out "try again". There are no other errors

Comment: I think it is a scoping error, but idk how to fix